# Coding Problem in IE and FF. Working in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

This has been driving me crazy for two days now... I have been trying to integrate a Big Cartel store into a site using their external API but I've got some issues getting the script working. It seems to be working how I want it in Chrome and Safari but not in FF and IE? The page I'm trying to get the products into is http://www.denimgeek.com/wp-content/featured.html (which currently works in chrome and safari).

The coding for the page is below, I'm in no way a Javascript programmer but any idea why this wouldn't work in those browsers?  Firefox keeps saying 'console not defined' and it doesn't work in IE8 but does after I go into developer tools and change the page mode to quirks?! It's driving me crazy!

The code of the page is below, am I missing something simple?

```
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.denimgeek.com/wp-content/themes/atlantica/style.css">   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
var subdomain = 'denimgeek';    
$(function() {
      function findImage(url, size) {
            if(!size) return url;
            var ext = url.match(/\.(\w{2,4}$)/)[1];
            var dir = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            switch(size.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'large':
                    return dir + '300.' + ext;
                case 'medium':
                    return dir + '175.' + ext;
                case 'thumb':
                    return dir + '75.' + ext;
                default:
                    return url;
            }
      }
      $.getJSON('http://api.bigcartel.com/' + subdomain + '/products.js?callback=?', function(products) {
      $.each(products, function(i, product) {
          console.log(product);
          $('#products').append('<li><img src="' + findImage(product.images[0].url, 'large') + '"><br><a href="http://' + subdomain + '.bigcartel.com' + product.url + '">' + product.name + '</a></li>');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>  <body>  <ol id="products"></ol></body></html>
```

Comment: next time, please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Well.. in your *Javascript code*, we can find:

```
console.log(product);
```

which does throw an error when there is no `console object` defined.
The `console object` is defined for instance by *Firebug* or *Chrome Developer tools*, aswell as IE8+ *Developer tools*.

But if you disable those tools, it'll throw either way. A good practice is to catch that yourself. I'm using this in my init scripts:

```
if(!('console' in window) ) {
    window.console = {}

    var arr = 'log error warn time timeEnd table profile profileEnd group groupEnd debug dir'.split(' ');

    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        console[arr[i]] = function() { };
    }
}
```

If you put that snippet somewhere to the beginning of your scripts, those `console.anything` debug outputs will not crash the entire application.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick replies.. I pasted this code in after var subdomain = 'denimgeek'; and now it works in Firefox but not IE!?  I'm halfway there!

Comment: @leeham: I modified the snippet. `forEach` is not available in some IE versions. This should fix it.

Comment: Now not working all! It's a nightmare!  Really appreciate the effort though man.. The page is now http://www.denimgeek.com/wp-content/featured4.html.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working! I removed the console.log. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @leeham: the problem is not in my snippet, you missed some semicolon somewhere it looks like.

Comment: No problem jAndy.. Glad I got it working.. again thanks for all your help!  One more question though, would there be any way to limited the number of products the script calls?  ie.  The number of times it 'appends' the code?

Answer (score 1):

Without a doctype, you are in quirks mode. Add this to your first line and see where we stand:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take out console.log as if you don't have firebug it will definitely crash ff or ie, unlike the webkit browsers which has console installed with them already